# TP Link T6E v2 wont connect to repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-extender

Today I received TP Link T6E v2.0 network card. Installed in PC, installed v2 driver for windows 10 and it wont let me connect to my repeater Asus RP-AC51.
Next to me I have set up my laptop as hotspot and it connects to it, but it won't connect to repeater.
Have searched, tried everything from TPLink support sites - manual install, reinstall, changing channels.Nothing helps.

Could it be an issue on the repeater side then if it wont let me connect to repeater straight away? I have changed settings in repeater, switched from 2.4 to 5 and other way. Added password, restarted repeater many times, but without any success.
Maybe someone has had an issue like this?
Thanks

Comment: What's the encryption set to? AES or TKIP or both?

Comment: If that you mean password and encryption. I have not set a password from repeater. Added password, didnt change anything

Comment: So no WPA2/PSK encryption set? What is the channel mode set to on the main AP? 20Mhz wide? Or is it 40Mhz?

Comment: Yes,no encryption set. And its set on automatic. I have a laptop in my room and it gets the connection from repeater/extender and works fine, but if I connect network card to to the exactsamenetwork, it shows either No internet, either cannot connect to the network. But.. If I create a hotspot from my laptop and connect to it from main pc with network card, it works well. There is some issue with repeater probably then, some settings maybe. I have tried different things. Nothing helped.

Comment: Your adapter may not be compatible with dynamic 20/40Mhz mode. Try setting it to 20Mhz only

Comment: Tried. Didnt work. I just reset my repeater, added networks, tried to connect - it connected, but internet wasnt working. Now I tried to connect again and it shows "No Internet" message again.

Comment: Connecting with no internet and not being able to connect to the wireless network are two very different problems. If you can connect but with no internet it's a config problem